# Writing to a read-only accessor c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, accessor

I'm trying to make something similar to ASP.NET's User.Identity.Name. I've already made the class to hold the information but I don't know how to write to the variable since I only added the get{};

```
private static string _firstName; 
public static string FirstName 
{ 
    get { return _firstName; } 
}
```

Comment: Either add the setter, or dont write to it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do this. The first way is adding a private setter.

```
private static string _firstName; 
public static string FirstName 
{ 
    get { return _firstName; }
    private set { _firstName = value; }
}
```

The other option is add a parameter to your constructor and set the value inside it.

```
public YourClass(string firstName)
{
    _firstName = firstName;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class YourAwesomeClass
  {
      private static string _firstName;
      public static string FirstName
       {
            get { return _firstName; }
        }
    public YourAwesomeClass(string firstName)
     {
     _firstName=firstName;
     }
  }
```

or you if are using Dotnet 3.0 or greater you can use automatic property, Compiler will automatically create backing fields for you.

```
public class YourAwesomeClass
      {

          public static string FirstName
           {
                get;private set;
            }
        public YourAwesomeClass(string firstName)
         {
         FirstName=firstName;
         }
      }
```

Comment: yeah it belong to class not to an instance

Comment: Good answer, but you forgot the underscore _firstName;

Answer (score 0):

Write a setter methode:

```
public static string FirstName
{
    get { return _firstName; }
    set { _firstName = value; }
}
```